# Difficult node.js + libuv + v8 error

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, libuv

I am doing some parallel work with **uv_queue_work** in a node.js c++ addon.

Everything works fine until I try to **callback to JS** from the Complete method.

I get: **CHECK(thread_local_top()->TryCatchHandler() == that) failed.**

Any pointers as to what could be causing this?

I am using the following code to callback:

```
    //Get emit method from JS object and check !IsEmpty and IsFunction
    v8::TryCatch tc;                
    emit->Call(pxy,1,argv);   // The error happens in this statement.
    if (tc.HasCaught()){
        //Some handler code
    }
```

Comment: Seems to me like you're trying to invoke the callback from another thread. Can you post some more code, like how exactly you're using uv_queue_work?

Comment: That was my first thought as well, I do have the following utility method running just before, which as I understand it, should be returning false if not on the V8 thread.

`bool Util::V8Thread(){
    return v8::Isolate::GetCurrent() != NULL;
};`

I am using the following to kick off the process:
uv_queue_work(loop,baton,Worker,WorkerComplete);
and the error is happening in "WorkerComplete"

Comment: assertion indicates that stack of try catch handlers somehow became unbalanced. it's hard to guess why without seeing more code or at least stack-trace from gdb.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a useful error description! Now I know what to look for :) 

The code is quite involved, so I think I am going to try to reproduce in a simple project. The GDB stack simply shows the uv methods, and the comlete callback... 

Hopefully I can get to the bottom of this!

Answer (score 0):

OK, not sure exactly why the error was happening, but I was able to make it go away by using node::MakeCallback instead of emit->Call.

Really unsure as to why this is happening, and a little worried as there has been talk about deprecating MakeCallback...

Edit:
I would be happy to accept any answer that can shed light on this. Hopefully the use of MakeCallback" saves someone else in the meantime :)